# c# add delay between concurrent task executions

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task

I have the following tasks that sends some data to a TCP Socket:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();

foreach(int patient in patients)
{
    //tasks.Add(Work(patient));
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        var message = BuildCommand();
        var bytes = Socket.StartClient(message);

        var bits = new BitArray(bytes);
        var stringBytes = ToBitString(bits);

        SetResultsText(stringBytes + Environment.NewLine);

    }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning));
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

What I want is to add a delay between each task of about `200ms` so they don't run exactly at the same time because I have seen that some packages are lost on the socket, so I want to delay a little bit each call to avoid this issue.

I have tried `Task.Delay` and `Thread.Sleep` and seems tasks still executing at same time.

Comment: use lock for that

Comment: @Arphile how? thanks

Comment: If you want them to run in sequence and there are no async operations inside the Task, why complicate things using tasks at all and not just run the code synchronously?

Comment: [`StartNew` is dangerous](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)

Comment: What's the point of creating new tasks, especially with LongRunning flag that eventually will force to create new threads when your intends are to launch them synchronously? Seriously, think about it. You only start them at the same time. But then you want to go for Thread.Sleep (block your threads) and then you are awaiting all of them at the end, which means you need to go further only when all of the tasks are done.so why won't you just do it synchronously?

Comment: @John_ReinstateMonica look at the code the OP provided. There's no reason to emit lots on threads here. It would work with just one task a lot faster, taking in account thread blocking and context switching with task.Sleep or Monitor as someone proposed. At the very least I would go for ManualResetEventSleep. But it's not even the case.

Comment: @Gleb, don't you mean sequentially?

Comment: @PauloMorgado yes. That's what I meant. I missed the word. Sorry for my English

Comment: @Gleb, not to miss your point, there's nothing asynchronous in that code. And, since it's supposed to be sequential, it becomes synchronous with a dose of thread waisting.

Comment: @PauloMorgado exactly!

Comment: You might want to use something like a user defined [TaskScheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=netframework-4.8)?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to run the tasks simultaneously anyway and assuming there's a reason not to just run the code synchronously removing the task entirely, it may be simpler to do everything in a single task sequentially instead;

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    foreach(int patient in patients)
    {
        var message = BuildCommand();
        var bytes = Socket.StartClient(message);

        var bits = new BitArray(bytes);
        var stringBytes = ToBitString(bits);
        SetResultsText(stringBytes + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

await task;
```

Answer (score 1):

IF what you want is to run them sequentially and with a delay, just do that:

```
var first = true;
foreach(int patient in patients)
{
    if (!first)
    {
        await Task.Delay(200);
    }

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var message = BuildCommand();
        var bytes = Socket.StartClient(message);
        var bits = new BitArray(bytes);
        var stringBytes = ToBitString(bits);

        SetResultsText(stringBytes + Environment.NewLine);
    });
 }
```

I think that's what you're asking, but I doubt very much that that's what you're needing. This is just a waste of threads.

Answer (score -2):

```
object LockObject { get; set; }

public void Init() {
    LockObject = new object();
}

...YourMethod() {
    lock ( LockObject ) {
        ...YourTask
    }
}
```

Call YourMethod() will do it step by step.

LockObject will locked until YourTask finished, after then, it'll call another methodcall which you called.

you don't need to add 200ms each of tasks.